# SQL JOIN with AND condition in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, join

How can I write this query in mongodb?

```
SELECT apple.id, peach.name
FROM apple
LEFT JOIN peach
ON apple.id = peach.id AND peach.name = "sweet"
WHERE apple.color = "red"
```

Comment: Please show us your Mongodb Model....

Comment: apple fields: id, color
peach fields: id, name
nev is name, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
db.apple.aggregate([{

    "$match": {
        "color": "red"
    },
},
{   
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "peach",
        "localField": "id",
        "foreignField": "id",
        "as": "peach"
    }
},
{   
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$peach",
        "includeArrayIndex": "arrayIndex",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }
},
{
  "$match": {
        "peach.name": "sweet"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        id: 1,
         peach_name: "$peach.id"
     }
}]);
```